# Slow Data analysis using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am using a mixture of both lists and pandas dataframes to accomplish a clean and merge of csv data. The following is a snippet from my code that runs disgustingly slow... Generates a csv with about 3MM lines of data.

```
UniqueAPI = Uniquify(API)
dummydata = []
#bridge the gaps in the data with zeros
for i in range(0,len(UniqueAPI)):
    DateList = []
    DaysList = []
    PDaysList = []
    OperatorList = []
    OGOnumList = []
    CountyList = []
    MunicipalityList = []
    LatitudeList = []
    LongitudeList = []
    UnconventionalList = []
    ConfigurationList = []
    HomeUseList = []
    ReportingPeriodList = []
    RecordSourceList = []

    for j in range(0,len(API)):
        if UniqueAPI[i] == API[j]:
            #print(str(ProdDate[j]))
            DateList.append(ProdDate[j])
            DaysList = Days[j]
            OperatorList = Operator[j]
            OGOnumList = OGOnum[j]
            CountyList = County[j]
            MunicipalityList = Municipality[j]
            LatitudeList = Latitude[j]
            LongitudeList = Longitude[j]
            UnconventionalList = Unconventional[j]
            ConfigurationList = Configuration[j]
            HomeUseList = HomeUse[j]
            ReportingPeriodList = ReportingPeriod[j]
            RecordSourceList = RecordSource[j]

    df = pd.DataFrame(DateList, columns = ['Date'])
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
    minDate = df.min()
    maxDate = df.max()

    Years = int((maxDate - minDate)/np.timedelta64(1,'Y'))
    Months = int(round((maxDate - minDate)/np.timedelta64(1,'M')))
    finalMonths = Months - Years*12 + 1
    Y,x = str(minDate).split("-",1)
    x,Y = str(Y).split("   ",1)
    for k in range(0,Years + 1):

        if k == Years:
            ender = int(finalMonths + 1)
        else:
            ender = int(13)

        full_df = pd.DataFrame()
        if k > 0:
            del full_df
            full_df = pd.DataFrame()

        full_df['API'] = UniqueAPI[i]
        full_df['Production Month'] =     [pd.to_datetime(str(x)+'/1/'+str(int(Y)+k)) for x in range(1,ender)]
        full_df['Days'] = DaysList
        full_df['Operator'] = OperatorList
        full_df['OGO_NUM'] = OGOnumList
        full_df['County'] = CountyList
        full_df['Municipality'] = MunicipalityList
        full_df['Latitude'] = LatitudeList
        full_df['Longitude'] = LongitudeList
        full_df['Unconventional'] = UnconventionalList
        full_df['Well_Configuration'] = ConfigurationList
        full_df['Home_Use'] = HomeUseList
        full_df['Reporting_Period'] = ReportingPeriodList
        full_df['Record_Source'] = RecordSourceList
        dummydata.append(full_df)

full_df = pd.concat(dummydata)                                   
result =  full_df.merge(dataClean,how='left').fillna(0)

print(result[:100])

result.to_csv(ResultPath, index_label=False, index=False)
```

This snippet of code has been running for hours the output should have ~3MM lines there has to be a faster way using pandas to accomplish the goal of which I will describe:

- for each unique API i find all occurrences in the main list of apis
- using that information i build a list of dates
- I find a min and max date for each list corresponding to an api
- I then build an empty pandas DataFrame that has every month between the two dates for the associated api
- I then append this data frame to a list "dummydata" and loop to the next api
- taking this dummy data list I then concatenate it into a DataFrame
- this DataFrame is then merged with another dataframe with cleaned data
- end result is a csv that has 0 value for dates that did not exist but should between the max and min dates for each corresponding API in the original unclean list

This all takes way longer than I would expect I would have thought that finding the min max date for each unique item and interpolating monthly between them filling in months that dont have data with 0 would be like a three line thing in Pandas. Any options that you guys think I should explore or any snippets of code that could help me out is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start by cleaning up the code a bit. These lines don't seem to have any effect or functional purpose since full_df was just created and is already an empty dataframe:

```
if k > 0:
    del full_df
    full_df = pd.DataFrame()
```

Then when you actually build up your full_df it's better to do it all at once rather than one column at a time. So try something like this:

```
full_df = pd.concat([UniqueAPI[i],
                     [pd.to_datetime(str(x)+'/1/'+str(int(Y)+k)) for x in range(1,ender)],
                     DaysList,
                     etc...
                     ],
                    axis=1)
```

Then you would need to add the column labels which you could also do all at once (in the same order as your lists in the concat() call).

full_df.columns = ['API', 'Production Month', 'Days', etc.]

Comment: OK thats great advice I suppose if I build the dataframe all at once I should have to worry about garbage collection which is what I was attempting to do with the delete line. The reason why I looped is that I need to go through multiple years is this something that I can avoid? I wasnt sure how to iterate through the years any other way.

Comment: The loop is a reasonable solution but I don't understand what it is you're doing with most of the variables in the second loop. Maybe you meant to append to the lists each time like you do to DateList but all the other ones you just rewrite over every time you get a hit in the second loop. If your second loop only has one possible answer, you could add a "break" statement at the end (of the second loop) so that it doesn't keep iterating over the rest of the possibilities. That should save loads of runtime.

Comment: I definitely would agree that this would decrease the amount of overhead quite substantially however I have not been able to figure out how to migrate this part out of the loop do to dummy data needing each api to have unique relations if I bring it one tab out I end up with a list twice as long and I have to transfer the list to a dataframe and then back to a list